# How to get daily PV from such table

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I have a table like this:

```
id   start_time,              end_time               pv 
1.   2021-09-10 00:00:00      2021-09-10 01:00:00   123
2.   2021-09-10 01:00:00      2021-09-10 02:00:00   124
3.   2021-09-10 02:00:00      2021-09-10 03:00:00   234
....

X.   2021-09-11 00:00:00      2021-09-11 01:00:00   143
...
Y.   2021-09-12 00:00:00      2021-09-12 01:00:00   133
```

I would like to get daily pv, how can I do that?

```
date        pv
2021-09-10  1234
2021-09-11  3456
```

currently I'm doing it repeatedly:

```
select sum(pv) from table where start_time>='2021-09-10 00:00:00' and end_time < '2021-09-11 00:00:00`
```

Comment: mysql and google bigquery are two different database products. Which one do you use?

Comment: I use both in my project, I don't mind use mysql or bigquery as long as this problem can be solved

Comment: It can be done in both, but the solutions may be different

Comment: OK, bigquery then

Answer (score 1):

It looks to me as simple as below

```
select date(start_time) date, sum(pv) pv
from table 
group by date
```